# Using smart card with firefox

Tags: firefox

I'm trying to use my smart card with firefox.

When I try to load a new module `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so`, it says "Unable to load module". There's no indication of why. The file exists. The card works in Chromium.

I am not using the snap version of firefox, I'm using one from apt. I have checked that it's installed in `/usr/lib/firefox`. I'm on version 122.0.1 (64-bit). I have Ubuntu 22.04 (cannot upgrade to a more modern version).